# Haskell: Data.HashSet (from unordered-container) Performance for Large Sets

Tags: performance, haskell, memory-management, hashset, unordered-containers

#### The data

First of all, let's generate some input so we have concrete data to talk about:

```
python -c 'for f in xrange(4000000):  print f' > input.txt
```

this will generate a file `input.txt` containing the numbers from 0 to 3999999, each on its own line. That means we should have a file with 4,000,000 lines, adding up to 30,888,890 bytes, roughly 29 MiB.

#### Everything as a list

Right, let's load everything into memory as a `[Text]`:

```
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Text (Text)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (runResourceT)
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB
import qualified Data.Conduit.Text as CT
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL

main :: IO ()
main = do
hs <- (runResourceT
          $ CB.sourceFile "input.txt"
         $$ CT.decode CT.utf8
         =$ CT.lines
         =$ CL.fold (\b a -> a `seq` b `seq` a:b) [])
print $ head hs
```

and run it:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, Test.o )
Linking Test ...
"3999999"
2,425,996,328 bytes allocated in the heap
972,945,088 bytes copied during GC
280,665,656 bytes maximum residency (13 sample(s))
5,120,528 bytes maximum slop
533 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
Gen  0      4378 colls,     0 par    0.296s   0.309s     0.0001s    0.0009s
Gen  1        13 colls,     0 par    0.452s   0.661s     0.0508s    0.2511s

INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
MUT     time    0.460s  (  0.465s elapsed)
GC      time    0.748s  (  0.970s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.002s  (  0.034s elapsed)
Total   time    1.212s  (  1.469s elapsed)

%GC     time      61.7%  (66.0% elapsed)

Alloc rate    5,271,326,694 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  38.3% of total user, 31.6% of total elapsed


real    0m1.481s
user    0m1.212s
sys 0m0.232s
```

runs in 1.4s, takes 533 MB of memory. As of [Haskell Wiki's Memory Footprint](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Memory_Footprint), the 4M `Text` instances should take 6 words + 2N bytes of memory. I'm on 64 bit so one word is 8 bytes. That means it should be (6 * 8 bytes * 4000000) + (2*26888890) bytes = 234 MiB. (The 26888890 are all the bytes in `input.txt` that are not newline characters). For the list which will hold them all, we'll need additional memory of   (1 + 3N) words + N * sizeof(v). sizeof(v) should be 8 because it'll be a pointer to the `Text`. The list should then use (1 + 3 * 4000000) * 8 bytes + 4000000 * 8 bytes = 122MiB. So in total (list + strings) we'd expect 356 MiB of memory used. I don't know where difference of 177 MiB (50%) of our memory went but let's ignore that for now.

#### The large hash set

Finally, we shall come to the use case that I'm actually interested in: Storing all the words in a large [`Data.HashSet`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.7.0/docs/Data-HashSet.html). For that, I changed the program ever so slightly

```
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Text (Text)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (runResourceT)
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB
import qualified Data.Conduit.Text as CT
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL
import qualified Data.HashSet as HS

main :: IO ()
main = do
hs <- (runResourceT
          $ CB.sourceFile "input.txt"
         $$ CT.decode CT.utf8
         =$ CT.lines
         =$ CL.fold (\b a -> a `seq` b `seq` HS.insert a b) HS.empty)
print $ HS.size hs
```

if we run that again

```
$ ghc -fforce-recomp -O3 -rtsopts Test.hs && time ./Test +RTS -sstderr
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, Test.o )
Linking Test ...
4000000
6,544,900,208 bytes allocated in the heap
6,314,477,464 bytes copied during GC
442,295,792 bytes maximum residency (26 sample(s))
8,868,304 bytes maximum slop
1094 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
Gen  0     12420 colls,     0 par    5.756s   5.869s     0.0005s    0.0034s
Gen  1        26 colls,     0 par    3.068s   3.633s     0.1397s    0.6409s

INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
MUT     time    3.567s  (  3.592s elapsed)
GC      time    8.823s  (  9.502s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.008s  (  0.097s elapsed)
Total   time   12.399s  ( 13.192s elapsed)

%GC     time      71.2%  (72.0% elapsed)

Alloc rate    1,835,018,578 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  28.8% of total user, 27.1% of total elapsed


real    0m13.208s
user    0m12.399s
sys 0m0.646s
```

it's quite bad: 13s and 1094MiB of memory used. The memory footprint page lists 4.5N words + N * sizeof(v) for a hash set, that should become (4.5 * 4000000 * 8bytes) + (4000000 * 8bytes) = 167 MiB. Adding the storage for the stings (234 MiB), I'd expect 401 MiB which is more than *double*, and it feels quite slow on top of that :(.

#### Thought experiment: manually managing the memory

As a thought experiment: Using a language where we can manually control memory layout and implement the HashSet with [Open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing) I'd expect the following to be the sizes. For fairness, I'll expect the strings to still be in UTF-16 (which is what `Data.Text` does). Given it's 26888890 characters in total (without newlines), the strings in UTF-16 should roughly be 53777780 bytes (2 * 26888890) = 51 MiB. We will need to store the length for every string, which will be 8 bytes * 4000000 = 30 MiB. And we will need space for the hash set (4000000 * 8 bytes), again 30 MiB. Given that the hash sets are normally increased exponentially, one would maybe expect 32 MiB or 64 MiB worst case. Let's go with the worst case: 64 MiB for the table + 30 MiB for the string lengths + 51 MiB for the actual string data, grand total of 145 MiB.

So given that `Data.HashSet` is not a specialised implementation for storing strings, the calculated 401 MiB would not be too bad but the actually used 1094 MiB seem a bit much waste.

#### The questions finally :)

So we finally got there:

- Where is the error in my calculations?
- Is there some problem in my implementation or is 1094 MiB really the best we can get?

#### Versions and stuff

- I should probably use `ByteString`s instead of `Text` as I only need ascii characters
- I'm on GHC 7.10.1 and `unordered-containers-0.2.5.1`

#### For comparison: 4,000,000 `Int`s:

```
import Data.List (foldl')
import qualified Data.HashSet as HS

main = do
    let hs = foldl' (\b a -> a `seq` b `seq` HS.insert a b) (HS.empty :: HS.HashSet Int) [1..4000000]
    print $ HS.size hs
```

doesn't look any better:

```
[...]
798 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)
[...]
real    0m9.956s
```

that's almost 800 MiB for 4M Ints!

Comment: To downvoters: can you leave a comment explaining what's wrong with the question?

Comment: Since you're using Haskell, you might want to generate your file using `ghc -e "mapM_ putStrLn [0..3999999]"`. I don't know if that's why people down-voted, but ... maybe?

Comment: This isn't relevant, but the uses of `seq` in your `HashSet` code are all redundant.

Comment: The errors in your calculation, after a rather fast skimming of your text, is that you aren't considering the memory overhead needed for garbage collection.  GHC uses generational GC and memory use isn't tight with the exact needs of the program, which should be obvious.  Adjusting the GC with RTS flags is one way to change the situation.

Comment: For the first example at least I think you nailed memory consumption pretty well: I get 237 MB of maximum residency (GHC 7.10.3, compiled with -O).

Comment: Re: my "which should be obvious" statement.  That seems snarky and rude on re-read so sorry about that, not sure why I included it.  At any rate, the question is well phrased and fairly complete but people do seem to forget that GC isn't free.  GHC's GC is well tuned to things that come up in the generated code, but it still is a long ways from perfect and should not be forgotten.

Comment: An important thing to remember, from the speed angle, is that code that violates the "generational hypothesis" by building up large values full of pointers will tend to be slow in the presence of tracing GC.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson indeed, I haven't really considered the GC overhead. Mostly because in the example where everything is sinked into a list, there shouldn't really be anything to GC, is there? For the HashSet example this is probably different. And it does indeed use over 1000MiB but if I run it with heap profiling, the resulting PostScript file maxes out at around 500 MiB which is pretty close to my calculations. Are there any GC settings I should consider in particular?

Comment: I ran your final test program (with no special parameters) and the program runs with ~70% GC time, 6GB allocated by the GC, ~10s total. With `+RTS -s -H1G`, ~45%, 900MB (6x less!) allocated by the GC, ~5s total. Increasing the size of the heap allows the GC to .. just not. Total allocation actually goes *up* but that isn't necessarily the only indicator of performance. Then I went crazy with `+RTS -s -H12G` - gives me 2% GC time, 80KB (!) allocated by the GC, 2s total. Moral of the story - the heap must be big enough to hold your entire (strict) data structure if you want it to go super fast.