# conduit: producing memory leak

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, conduit, attoparsec

Working on some observations on a previous question ([haskell-data-hashset-from-unordered-container-performance-for-large-sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251583/)) I stumbled upon a strange memory leak

```
module Main where

import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (runResourceT)
import Data.Attoparsec.ByteString (sepBy, Parser)
import Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8 (decimal, char)
import Data.Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.Attoparsec as CA
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL

main :: IO ()
main = do (args:_) <- getArgs
          writeFile "input.txt" $ unlines $ map show [1..4 :: Int]
          case args of "list" -> m1
                       "fail" -> m2
                       "listlist" -> m3
                       "memoryleak" -> m4
                       --UPDATE
                       "bs-lines":_ -> m5
                       "bs":_ -> m6
                       _ -> putStr $ unlines ["Usage: conduit list"
                                             ,"               fail"
                                             ,"               listlist"
                                             ,"               memoryleak"
                                             --UPDATE
                                             ,"               bs-lines"
                                             ,"               bs"
                                             ]
m1,m2,m3,m4 :: IO ()
m1 = do hs <- runResourceT
            $  CB.sourceFile "input.txt"
            $$ CB.lines
           =$= CA.conduitParser (decimal :: Parser Int)
           =$= CL.map snd
           =$= CL.consume
        print hs
m2 = do hs <- runResourceT
            $  CB.sourceFile "input.txt"
            $$ CA.conduitParser (decimal :: Parser Int)
           =$= CL.map snd
           =$= CL.consume
        print hs
m3 = do hs <- runResourceT
            $  CB.sourceFile "input.txt"
            $$ CB.lines
           =$= CA.conduitParser (decimal `sepBy` (char '\n') :: Parser [Int])
           =$= CL.map snd
           =$= CL.consume
        print hs
m4 = do hs <- runResourceT
            $  CB.sourceFile "input.txt"
            $$ CA.conduitParser (decimal `sepBy` (char '\n') :: Parser [Int])
           =$= CL.map snd
           =$= CL.consume
        print hs
-- UPDATE
m5 = do inpt <- BS.lines <$> BS.readFile "input.txt"
        let Right hs =  mapM (parseOnly (decimal :: Parser Int)) inpt
        print hs
m6 = do inpt <- BS.readFile "input.txt"
        let Right hs =  (parseOnly (decimal `sepBy` (char '\n') :: Parser [Int])) inpt
        print hs
```

Here is some example output:

```
$ > stack exec -- example list
[1234]
$ > stack exec -- example listlist
[[1234]]
$ > stack exec -- conduit fail
conduit: ParseError {errorContexts = [], errorMessage = "Failed reading: takeWhile1", errorPosition = 1:2}
$ > stack exec -- example memoryleak
(Ctrl+C)

-- UPDATE
$ > stack exec -- example bs-lines
[1,2,3,4]
$ > stack exec -- example bs
[1,2,3,4]
```

Now the questions I have is:

- **Why is `m1` not producing `[1,2,3,4]`?**
- **Why is `m2` failing?**
- **Why is `m4` behaving totally different compared to all other versions  and producing a space leak?**

Comment: Did you check your code using just lazy I/O and attoparsec itself? I wouldn't be surprised if the backtracking in attoparsec is holding onto the data longer than expected.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman I updated my question with a bytestring/attoparsec version, but I am not sure wether it is equivalent to the conduit version (for I am not too familiar with conduit). At least it is producing the output I expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is m2 failing?

The input file as a character stream is:

```
1\n2\n3\n4\n
```

Since the `decimal` parser do not expect a newline character, after consuming the first number the remaining stream is:

```
\n2\n3\n4\n
```

As the input stream is not exhausted,  `conduitParser` will run the parser on the stream again, this time it cannot even consume the first character so it failed.

> Why is m4 behaving totally different compared to all other versions and producing a space leak?

`` decimal `sepBy` (char '\n') `` will only consume `\n` between two integers, after successfully parsed four numbers, the input stream has only one character in it:

```
\n
```

and `` decimal `sepBy` (char '\n') `` cannot consume it, even worse it will not fail: `sepBy` can consume nothing and return empty list. Therefore it parse nothing infinitely and never terminate.

> Why is m1 not producing [1,2,3,4]?

I want to know it too! I guess it has something to do with fusing, maybe you should contact the author of conduit package, who just commented your question.

Comment: Since the explanation is too long for a comment, I added it as another answer.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question about m1: when you use `CB.lines`, you're turning input that looks like:

```
["1\n2\n3\n4\n"]
```

into:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Then, attoparsec parses the "1", waits for more input, sees the "2", and so on.

Comment: is it then incorrect to use `conduitParser` should I rather use vanilla `parseOnly` and `CL.map`, if I understand correctly `conduitParser` parses a stream incrementally and is not the right choice for parsing `[1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. Combining `CB.lines` and `conduitParser` is problematic because the former strips out the newlines that the latter needs to do proper parsing.